# unable to get java swing components

Tags: java, swing

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class Fram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTextArea map;
        JButton btn;
        map= new JTextArea();
        btn= new JButton("hello");
        JFrame frame= new JFrame("jarvis");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600,600);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(map, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}
```

I am using this code to get a text area but I only get the frame without any textarea or button.

Comment: It shouldn't even compile, as `Button` should be `JButton`, but if you fix that, it does show a frame with both a textarea and button. Perhaps you forgot to recompile after editing?

Comment: that is ok its just a miss print but still i am getting empty frame

Comment: it is working for me as well.

Comment: yes u guys are right it is working when i am compiling it directly from command prompt but when i am using ecliplse ide there i am getting an empty frame

Comment: Try using Project -> Clean on the menu to re-compile everything.

Comment: `frame.setVisible()` _after_ adding all your components. Think about it logically. Why would you want to make your frame visible before ever adding anything. I don't get what people don't understand about this simple logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine to me as well. 
You mentioned `you can not see swing component` I think the reason you are not seeing your text area as expected because that text area is occupying the complete space in the border layout so you are not able to discern if you have the text area. So I have added a JPanel and JscrollPane in your code to improve the behavior. I would also like to call setVisible as last method and as mention by Gilbert you you must start all Swing applications with a call to SwingUtilities invokeLater.

```
package stackOverFlow;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class Frame implements Runnable {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Frame());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JTextArea map;
        JButton btn;
        JLabel lbl;
        map = new JTextArea(10, 50);
        final JScrollPane scrollPanel = new JScrollPane(map);
        btn = new JButton("hello");
        lbl = new JLabel("Text Area: ");
        final JPanel actionPanel = new JPanel(
                new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        actionPanel.add(lbl);
        actionPanel.add(scrollPanel);
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("jarvis");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(actionPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

the output of program is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me.  I've added a couple of things you left out.

First, you **must** start all Swing applications with a call to SwingUtilities invokeLater.  This ensures that your Swing components are defined and executed on the [Event Dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (EDT).

Second, I moved the frame setVisible method last.  You need to completely set up your JFrame before you make it visible.

Here's the modified code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Fram implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JTextArea map;
        JButton btn;
        map = new JTextArea();
        btn = new JButton("hello");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("jarvis");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(map, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Fram());
    }


}
```

Comment: It really took 48 mins for someone to finally spot the most obvious setVisible <shaking head> +1

Comment: @peeskillet I spotted it. I didn't point it out because I knew it didn't matter.

Comment: @peeskillet: Sorry, I just got to this question.  :-)  I've admired and upvoted a bunch of your answers.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc [The system won't let you do that.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Comment: @Boann: I up vote as I come across peeskillet's answers to questions.  And yes, the system allows for that.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set size of buttons.It can be on center or south but you should declare it's size. so i prefer you  `btn.setBounds(0,0,100,20)`  if that wouldn't work you can delete BorderLayour.CENTER and set the bounds 200,280